# MPAndroidChart error class ValueFormatter not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After updating the MPAndroidChart library [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in our project from 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.25 to 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2 an error occurs that states that the class ValueFormatter cannot be found. On further research, it seems someone made a mistake on the maven repository artefact index as it seems that v2.2.5 is the latest version and v3.0.2 is not the most recently updated version [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using this version on a working project

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
```

And for formatting X and Y I'm using the followings imports

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IAxisValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IValueFormatter;
```

implementation look like this

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0"); // use one decimal
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        // write your logic here
        return mFormat.format(value) + ""; // e.g. append a dollar-sign
    }
}
```